# Where is the compass chip on the Nexus 6p?

Tags: sensors, nexus-6p, compass

I just replace the screen+lcd on my nexus 6p and the compass stopped working (this is not just a calibration issue, it looks like the compass chip is dead).

I think that I might have damaged the compass chip while replacing the screen. Do you know where the chip inside the phone so I can check? I looked online for circuit labels, but could not find anything regarding the location of the compass. I hope it's not just embedded in the motherboard.

Comment: I think its part of the GPS?

Comment: that's weird because my gps works, but not the compass :S

Comment: The compass in my phone has been broken for years without too much of an effect on the phone's usability, just so you know.

Comment: Ah, ok pipo, I'll look around.